# How to deny access to all pages in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I need to deny access to all pages excepting one to user with role ROLE_UNFILLED_USER. How can I do this using access_control in security.yml

Comment: You should check the documentation on *Security* [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html]. If what you are trying to achieve is deny anonymous access, i.e. deny access to anyone who is not logged in, you can just use `anonymous: false` in your firewall definition. Maybe you could expand on why you need the additional role and how your security.yml looks? This would make it easier to help and see if you are tackling your problem in a "wrong" way.

Comment: I need that user who doesnt specify all info could view only one page - /user/worksheet His role is USER_UNFILLED_USER 
Other users (that specified all info) can view all pages excepting /user/worksheet
Here is a part of my security.yml
<pre>
security: true
      anonymous: ~ 

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
    - { path: ^/bill, roles: ROLE_USER}
    - { path: ^/address_book, role: ROLE_USER } 
    - { path: ^/friendinvite, role: ROLE_USER } 
    - { path: ^/user/worksheet, role: ROLE_UNFILLED_USER }  
    - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to define a role hierarchy, where `ROLE_USER` inherits from `ROLE_UNFILLED_USER`:

```
# app/config/security.yml

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_UNFILLED_USER   # <-- This is the crucial part
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_API_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
```

Now you can place your access controls:

```
access_control:
    - { path: "^/user/worksheet", roles: ROLE_UNFILLED_USER }
    - { path: "^/bill", roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: "^/address_book", roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: "^/friendinvite", roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: "^/admin", roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    #- { path: "^/", roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Whenever a user with the role `ROLE_UNFILLED_USER` tries to access a route other than `^/user/worksheet` they should see a 403 (Forbidden). If you add other routes, make sure to order them correctly; Symfony will use the first matching route it finds, this means the more specific routes should be on the top of the list, the more generic routes at the bottom!

Since  `ROLE_USER` extends `ROLE_UNFILLED_USER`, users with that role may access all pages (including the worksheet).

There is a caveat to your approach though, when users login they are automatically redirected either to a specified target_path or the previously requested path. This means, if your user logs in, they will most likely see a 403-page and will be confused as to why they don't have access. Solution: Create a custom [AuthenticationProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) (especially look at the [Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener)).

Comment: It's not exactly what is needed. Anonymous users can view some pages and users with role ROLE_USER can view all pages excepting /user/worksheet

Comment: @Ofer I fixed my answer with the routes you provided.

Comment: there is no expected effect with this configuration - I can view any page(if it isnt closed like /admin or /bill) under ROLE_UNFILLED_USER. I'll try to expalain. Anonimous user can view all pages that dont close directly. ROLE_USER can view all pages excepting /user/worksheet . ROLE_UNFILLED_USER can view only /user/worksheet

Comment: What does "that don't close directly?" mean? In your scenario `ROLE_USER` does not extend `ROLE_UNFILLED_USER`, so just remove that from role_hierarchy. Now `^/user/worksheet` should only be accessible from `ROLE_UNFILLED_USER`.  If you want you can ditch the hierarchy and define the access_controls for each role specifically like this: `{ path: "^/bill", roles: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN ] }` and so forth. I really don't see what your problem is, other than figuring out which roles have access to which paths?

Comment: Yes, I know how to make that /user/worksheet could view only ROLE_UNFILLED_USER but I don't understand how to deny him access to other pages. There are hundreds of URLs in my project. Its too much routine to type the rule for each path.

Comment: It is quite easy. Either you set `anonymous: true` in your firewall configuration, and specify which routes are not open to everyone, i.e. restrict access, or you set `anonymous: false`, all routes are restricted to logged in users and then you specify who has access to what. Using the hierarchy you can have inherit some of the routes from other roles, so that you do not need to specify them again. If you have semantic urls it should be quite easy to determine who has access to what and then specify these routes, other than that I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: Here is a little typo `RULE_USER` in role_hierarchy section

Comment: Yes, nicely spotted. Thank you. I made an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Login Listener and redirect the user if he has a certain role. Or maybe just use a request listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

in security section your security.yaml file. This settings allow you to protect all pages of your site except one (login form matched "/login")